# Trying to understand how impedance transformation happens in this RF circuit

Tags: rf

[image]

[image]

[image]

So right at the end it is said that the RF side of the baseband appears as +Vbb/2, how? I dont understand that.

According to the text underlined in red this circuit doesn't have reverse isolation, for my understanding if i have some RF voltage in the RF port i would have some part of that signal come back into that same port (Vbb(t)/2) , how is that any good?
The only thing that can benefit for this is if i want this circuit to behave like an upconversion circuit where i have a signal at the BB port where that originates a RF signal that multiplies the BB signal with cos(wLO).

In equation (2) why is there a factor of 2/pi in the second expression? Also that expression doesnt look like like Vbb(t)/2..

And my last question is how is this part of the arcticle related to impedance transformation (it says in the intro)? I think i'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So right at the end, it is said that the RF side of the baseband appears as +Vbb/2, how?

The baseband voltage appears on the RF side when the switch is on. And this is because there is no reverse isolation, as in the case of the active mixer where the input is applied to the gate of the transistor providing the isolation. And this is not a positive point for the passive mixers. But the passive mixers are beneficial because they consume less power and have low flicker noise that helps for zero IF downconversion.

> In equation (2) why is there a factor of 2/pi in the second expression? Also that expression doesnt look like like Vbb(t)/2

As said in the text, the BB voltage of \$\pm\frac{v_{BB}}{2}\$ appears at the RF side depending if the top switch or the bottom switch is on. Since the system is linear (although time-varying) superposition principle can be applied. Assuming, zero input current, the BB voltage appears at the RF side modulated by a differential square wave. And is given by:
$$
v_{RF1} = \frac{4}{\pi}cos(\omega_{LO}t)\frac{v_{BB}}{2}
$$
And assuming \$v_{BB} = 0\$, and since one of the switches is always on,
$$
v_{RF2} = R_{SW}i_{RF}(t)
$$
Add these two to get \$v_{RF}\$ and substitute equation 1 for \$v_{BB}\$ to get equation 2.

> And my last question is how is this part of the arcticle related to impedance transformation (it says in the intro)?

Well, read ahead, the author has derived the expression for the input impedance seen at the RF side. And explains how the baseband impedance needs to be transformed at the RF side.

Comment: I dont understand what happens when vbb is 0. If it is 0 how is there irf current?

Comment: The iRF current comes from the preceding stage, not vBB.

Comment: At the very end of the image i posted why do the authors say VRF produced by a singletone RF current at wLO + Wm, what's Wm?

Comment: the difference between rf and lo frequency